# CSS files loaded but not rendered Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ecs, gunicorn

I have a Django app with Gunicorn and Nginx deployed on AWS ECS. NGINX can load static files but the page still shows only text.

Nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name api.example.com;

  location /health {
    access_log off;
    return 200;
  }

  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  proxy_send_timeout 300;

  # Main app
  location / {
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE|PATCH)$) {
      return 405;
    }

    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    proxy_pass http://example-api:8000;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port     $http_x_forwarded_port;
  }

  location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /my_app/static/;
  }
}
```

In settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/my_app/static/'
```

When I inspect the webpage, all CSS files are loaded, no 404 (It was an issue before but I fixed that). So not sure what else I am missing here.

The UI works fine when running without Nginx and `runserver`, but on AWS ECS, I use `gunicorn`.

[image: With Nginx and Gunicorn]

[image: With runserver command]